# Advisable to touch the codes in Designer.cs file?

Tags: winforms

Is it advisable for me to touch the designer.cs file for my windows form application? As I am referencing the labels to my settings file, I plan to code it in such a way that if my settings file shows

```
int startup = 0;
```

the code handler for my combo box selection would be

```
if (settingObject.bootOnStartup == 0)
        {
            comboStartup.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            comboStartup.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
```

it does works for its function but it sort of crashes the design window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't modify the .designer.cs files, ever. Whatever you do in it, it will be overwritten the next time you edit your Form in the designer, so you will have to do it again. I don't see any reason not to put this code in the Form constructor or the `Load` event...

Answer (score 1):

Your last sentence is the answer. If anything needs special treatment, do it in the user part of the partial class. Even if in your case (I'm speculating) this would require creating a ComboBox manually before the designer code runs.

The only time I touch the designer code is when I simply and quickly want to change something that I'm sure will survive the code generation of VS, e.g. a property name in a binding.

Answer (score 1):

The Designer.cs file tells you not to modify:

```
/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
private void InitializeComponent( ) {

    /* ...control customization from designer... */

}
```

If you have modifications then make those in your Form constructor after `InitializeComponent`:

```
public MainForm( ) {
    InitializeComponent( );

    if (settingObject.bootOnStartup == 0) {
        comboStartup.SelectedIndex = 0;
    } else {
        comboStartup.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
}
```

... or, on a `this.Load` event:

```
public MainForm( ) {
    InitializeComponent( );
    this.Load += (s, e) => {
        if (settingObject.bootOnStartup == 0) {
             comboStartup.SelectedIndex = 0;
         } else {
             comboStartup.SelectedIndex = 1;
         }
    };
}
```